# HTTP/1.1 202 (Accepted) POSTING FORM DATA VIA HTTPS to WCF SERVICE

Tags: wcf, web-services, https, forms, http-post

Hey does anyone get a "202 (Accepted)" issue posting form data to a WCF service hosted via SSL? 
What I am expecting is a response in xml. This works in regular http and visual studio debugging.
--Edit--
The service works as expected only when all source files are published.

Comment: Fixed the issue. The problem was that the datacontract required an xsd resource that was included with the all files publishing option. So I had to use the process of elimination to find the file required. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Found the xsd file the app was looking for.See response above